# Testing a server with WAN addresses on the local network

Tags: linux, networking, web-server, linux-networking

(Hope I can make clear what I'm asking. English is not my native language)

I'm building a webserver that will get 8 different fixed WAN IP addresses: x.y.z.1 -> x.y.z.8 (for example). My local network is in the 192.168.1.x range.

I want to test the webserver on my local network.

For testing, I could replace all references on the server of x.y.z.n addresses to the 192.168.1.x range. But there are many, many places where this needs to be done. So I'd rather not.

I used to have a dd-wrt based router that acted like a DHCP server for my local network. And for testing, I simply had it hand out ip-addresses in the x.y.z.n range so everything on the local network would be in the same subnet as the server. But I don't have that router any more.

Is there a way I could test the server on my local network without having to change the ip-addresses on it?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you may change addresation in your lan to non private diapason of ip addresses. Possibly internet access on your web servers may be lost.
Another variant -- add second ip addresses to network interfaces of your web servers. For example: `sudo ip addr add dev wlan0 1.2.3.4`.